# Select insert update in sql store procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I trying to get the single values from my created procedure but is showing error  as `Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <,`
Basicly i want to return single value of `@statusReturn` , but how ever i am not able to do that can anyone tell how to achive this.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [DBO].[uspGetJobStausAnyalyticaSpdDeltaRefresh]
( @Execution_Job_ID INT) 
AS 
  BEGIN
  SELECT TOP 3 
               ji.jobname, 
               jel.* 
    INTO       #tempjobstatus 
    FROM       jobexecutionlog jel  
    INNER JOIN jobinfo ji 
    ON         jel.jobid=ji.jobid 
    WHERE      jel.jobid IN (897,809,876) 
    AND        jel.jobexecutionlogid <= @Execution_Job_ID 
    ORDER BY   2 DESC 
    
    DECLARE @statusSPDRefresh  VARCHAR(30), 
      @statusAnalyticsRefresh  VARCHAR(30), 
      @statusJobExecutionLogId INT , 
      @statusReturn            INT
      SET @statusSPDRefresh = 
    ( 
           SELECT jobstatus 
           FROM   #tempjobstatus 
           WHERE  jobname ='Refresh')
           IF (@statusSPDRefresh = 'Failed') 
    BEGIN 
      SET @statusAnalyticsRefresh = 
      ( 
             SELECT jobstatus 
             FROM   #tempjobstatus 
             WHERE  jobname ='AnaRefresh') 
      IF (@statusAnalyticsRefresh = 'In Progress') 
      BEGIN 
        SET @statusJobExecutionLogId = 
        ( 
               SELECT jobexecutionlogid 
               FROM   #tempjobstatus 
               WHERE  jobname ='AnaRefresh') 
        UPDATE jobexecutionlog 
        SET    jobstatus = 'Failed' 
        WHERE  jobexecutionlogid = @statusJobExecutionLogId 
        SET    @statusReturn=1 
      END 
      ELSE SET @statusReturn =0
    END 
    ELSE  IF (@statusSPDRefresh = 'Completed') 
    BEGIN 
      SET @statusAnalyticsRefresh = 
      ( 
             SELECT jobstatus 
             FROM   #tempjobstatus 
             WHERE  jobname ='AnaRefresh') 
      IF (@statusAnalyticsRefresh = 'In Progress') 
      BEGIN 
        SET @statusJobExecutionLogId = 
        ( 
               SELECT jobexecutionlogid 
               FROM   #tempjobstatus 
               WHERE  jobname ='AnaRefresh') 
        UPDATE jobexecutionlog 
        SET    jobstatus = 'Completed' 
        WHERE  jobexecutionlogid = @statusJobExecutionLogId 
        SET    @statusReturn=1 
      END 
      ELSE SET @statusReturn =0
    END 
    ELSE 
   BEGIN 
    SET @statusReturn=0 
    END
    DROP TABLE #tempjobstatus
    END
```

Comment: If you want to return a value, either use a user-defined function or an output parameter.

Comment: FYI: [Bad habits to kick : ORDER BY ordinal](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/06/bad-habits-to-kick-order-by-ordinal). *Especially* when you've used `jel.*`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of constructs like this:

```
set @SomeVariable = (select ...)
```

But what should SQL do if the select statement returns more than one value? For example:

```
create table t(i int)
go
insert t values (1), (2)
go
declare @i int;
set @i = (select i from t);
```

I have two values in my `t` table: 1, and 2. What do we do here? We can't assign both values to a single variable. So SQL says "I don't know what I'm supposed to do here".

That's why you're getting the error. It means at least one of your `set @variable = (select ...)` queries against your `#tempjobstatus` table returns more than one row for the select statement you're using.

You can "force" a single row to be returned, for example by using `top 1`, but that's probably just going to introduce a bug. Because if there's more than one row, which one do you want to return with `top 1`?

If all of the rows are identical, then you can use `distinct`:

```
set @myvariable  = (select distinct somevalue from sometable)
```

But if there's more than one distinct value, that's obviously not going to help.

We can't give you "the solution" here. You need to think about the data that might exist in your particular system, and what you're trying to do with it. But hopefully this answer helps you understand the problem.